# Comparing List against Dict - return key if value matches list

Tags: python, dictionary

This is Python 3.6

I need help comparing a list against a dictionary and if there is match I need to return the dictionaries key.

```
champ_ids = [0, 36, 85]

champ_dict = {Bob : 0, Carly: 36, Freddy : 85, Megan : 14, Dilbert : 69}

for item in champ_dict.items() and champ_ids:
    print(item)
```

That prints all the matching numbers so in this case `0, 36, 85` which is perfect. How do I make it return `Bob, Carly, Freddy` (the keys) if those values are found in both places, instead of returning the values that match

Comment: I edited my question - 3.6 is the version

Comment: careful, `for item in champ_dict.items() and champ_ids:` is not doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that this code in the question is *not* doing what you imagine:

```
for item in champ_dict.items() and champ_ids:
```

The above does *not* check if the `item` is in both the dictionary and the list (that's not how `in`, `and` work in Python!). It's simply iterating over the `champ_ids` list, and nothing more. Try this instead:

```
champ_ids  = [0, 36, 85]
champ_dict = {'Bob' : 0, 'Carly': 36, 'Freddy' : 85, 'Megan' : 14, 'Dilbert' : 69}
[k for k, v in champ_dict.items() if v in champ_ids]
```

The above will compare each *value* in the dictionary and if it's present in the list it'll add the corresponding *key* to an output list. For instance, this is the output for the test data in the question:

```
['Freddy', 'Bob', 'Carly']
```

Now you can use it as needed, `print()` it if you want.

Comment: nitpick: it's better to unpack `for k,v in some_dict.items()` idiom than indexing a tuple.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Of course! I forgot about it. Thanks!

Comment: That seems to work, curious though why is that a better solution than TheEpicMelon gives below, which is easier to understand IMO?

Comment: @MingyJ in Python we prefer to use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (the feature I'm using in my solution) instead of explicit loops, comprehensions are not just more idiomatic, also are faster. Also, it's not a good idea to print things inside a loop, better create a list with the answer and then pass it around for further processing

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense now. Also, thanks for editing your question to explain why my first line was wrong, much appreciated!

Comment: @MingyJ always my pleasure :) have fun!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have strings as keys in your dictionary

```
{"Bob" : 0, "Carly" : 36, "Freddy" : 85, "Megan" : 14, "Dilbert" : 69}
```

Also why not use the id as the key instead of the name,
that would be a bit nicer

But here is the code:

```
for k, v in champ_dict.items():
    if v in champ_ids:
        print(k)
```