# Match list elements with values of dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I have dictionaries inside list as:-

```
L= [{'id': 3, 'term': 'bugatti', 'bucket_id': 'ad_3'},
     {'id': 4, 'term': 'mercedez', 'bucket_id': 'ad_4'},
     {'id': 8, 'term': 'entertainment', 'bucket_id': 'ad_8'},
     {'id': 8, 'term': 'entertainment', 'bucket_id': 'ad_8'},
     {'id': 9, 'term': 'music', 'bucket_id': 'ad_9'}]
```

and another list as:-

```
words=['bugatti', 'entertainment', 'music','politics']
```

All I want to map elements of list `words` with key `term` and wants to get corresponding dictionary. Output expected as:

```
new_list= [{'id': 3, 'term': 'bugatti', 'bucket_id': 'ad_3'},
           {'id': 8, 'term': 'entertainment', 'bucket_id': 'ad_8'},
           {'id': 8, 'term': 'entertainment', 'bucket_id': 'ad_8'},
           {'id': 9, 'term': 'music', 'bucket_id': 'ad_9'}]
```

What I have tried as:

```
for d in L:
    for k,v in d.items():
        for w in words:
            if v==w:
                print (k,v)
```

gives me only:

```
term bugatti
term entertainment
term entertainemnt
term music
```

Comment: Please take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056275/comparing-list-against-dict-return-key-if-value-matches-list

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
L= [{'id': 3, 'term': 'bugatti', 'bucket_id': 'ad_3'},
     {'id': 4, 'term': 'mercedez', 'bucket_id': 'ad_4'},
     {'id': 8, 'term': 'entertainment', 'bucket_id': 'ad_8'},
     {'id': 8, 'term': 'entertainment', 'bucket_id': 'ad_8'},
     {'id': 9, 'term': 'music', 'bucket_id': 'ad_9'}]


words=['bugatti', 'entertainment', 'music','politics']

print([i for i in L if i["term"] in words])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'bucket_id': 'ad_3', 'id': 3, 'term': 'bugatti'},
 {'bucket_id': 'ad_8', 'id': 8, 'term': 'entertainment'},
 {'bucket_id': 'ad_8', 'id': 8, 'term': 'entertainment'},
 {'bucket_id': 'ad_9', 'id': 9, 'term': 'music'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension but I included the full loop so you can see the logic more clearly

```
new_l = [i for i in l if i['term'] in words]
```

Full loop

```
new_l = []
for i in l:
    if i['term'] in words:
        new_l.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print [dict for dict in L if dict["term"] in words]
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are printing `(k,v)` which is just the key and the value of one dictionary entry. If you want to have the whole dictionary you have to put the whole dictionary in the print Statement.

```
for d in L:
    for k,v in d.items():
        for w in words:
            if v==w:
                print (d)
```